# Dynamic creation of array

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to form a request objects from the events,

`this.totalEvents` as the below property,

```
[{proposalNo: "1524472817264", events: Array(1)}]
```

Below is my code for creating a request Obj,

```
 for (let i = 0; i < this.totalEvents.length; i++) {
        let j = 
          {
            "events": this.totalEvents[i].events,
            "proposalNo": this.totalEvents[i].proposalNo
          }
        Obj.push(j);       
      }    

      let requestObj = JSON.stringify(Obj)
```

**Expected output**

```
[
  {
    "events": [
      1524053212499, 1524053003800
    ],
    "proposalNo": 1523036713813
  },  
  {
    "events": [1524056044007],
    "proposalNo": 1523036731774
  }
]
```

Issue is, i getting this error `Unexpected token h in JSON at position 0`

Comment: `this.totalEvents` is an Object, not an Array. Objects don't have a length

Comment: What is `Obj` in your code? Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha)).

Comment: obj is just empty array `Obj = []`

Comment: at which line do you get that error `Unexpected token h in JSON at position 0`?

Comment: `this._dataService.httpPost(url,requestObj)
      .subscribe(data => {   ` this line is causing the error

Comment: Can you show how your event object looks like?

Comment: Besides, I don't get it. You're not changing anything. The input and output objects have the same two keys, `events` and `proposalNo`. Basically you're duplicating `this.totalEvents` into `Obj`... What's the point?

Comment: Can you show us what's in `this.totalEvents`?

Comment: Can't reproduce this issue. See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kzjdhrLf/).

Comment: Can you print the result of the JSON serialization? `let requestObj = JSON.stringify(Obj)` it seems like the JSON passed to your post request is invalid.

Answer (score -1):

It's not clear from your code what `Obj` variable is, but if it is an object, then you cannot use `push` method on it. `push()` is for array.
Otherwise just log requestObj to console to see what it is and why it's not a valid json

Comment: In that case, OP would have received an error such as `push is not a function` or so.